# TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined json react-js

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

This is my first React app and I have used the api before also for the same purpose and it worked but without using React. What am I doing wrong.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import CardArray from './CardArray'
class Popular extends Component {

   constructor() {
        super()

        this.state = {
            movies : {}
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {

        fetch('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=key&language=en-US&page=1')
      .then(response=> response.json())
      .then(response => {this.setState({ movies : response})});

    }

    render() {

        var popularMovies = this.state.movies.results[0]; //this line has error

        console.log(popularMovies)

        return(
            <div>
                <h1 className="popular-heading">POPULAR MOVIES</h1>
                <CardArray popularMovies={popularMovies}/>
            </div>
        );

    };

}
export default Popular;
```

I am trying to get data from the API which is in JSON form. I fetch the code and log it in console and the whole JSON file is there but if try to get results[0] from JSON file I get Error. What am I doing wrong.

[Error from Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2eAFm.jpg)

The json I get is (removed some of the objects from results array)

```
    {
  "page": 1,
  "total_results": 19865,
  "total_pages": 994,
  "results": [
    {
      "vote_count": 397,
      "id": 351286,
      "video": false,
      "vote_average": 6.7,
      "title": "Jurassic World: Fallen Kingdom",
      "popularity": 395.188765,
      "poster_path": "/c9XxwwhPHdaImA2f1WEfEsbhaFB.jpg",
      "original_language": "en",
      "original_title": "Jurassic World: Fallen Kingdom",
      "genre_ids": [
        28,
        12,
        878
      ],
      "backdrop_path": "/t0Kn7twXduHeFhOpTW2Gncu9l5F.jpg",
      "adult": false,
      "overview": "A volcanic eruption threatens the remaining dinosaurs on the island of Isla Nublar, where the creatures have freely roamed for several years after the demise of an animal theme park known as Jurassic World. Claire Dearing, the former park manager, has now founded the Dinosaur Protection Group, an organization dedicated to protecting the dinosaurs. To help with her cause, Claire has recruited Owen Grady, a former dinosaur trainer who worked at the park, to prevent the extinction of the dinosaurs once again.",
      "release_date": "2018-06-06"
    },
    {
      "vote_count": 2107,
      "id": 383498,
      "video": false,
      "vote_average": 7.8,
      "title": "Deadpool 2",
      "popularity": 218.858604,
      "poster_path": "/to0spRl1CMDvyUbOnbb4fTk3VAd.jpg",
      "original_language": "en",
      "original_title": "Deadpool 2",
      "genre_ids": [
        28,
        35,
        878
      ],
      "backdrop_path": "/3P52oz9HPQWxcwHOwxtyrVV1LKi.jpg",
      "adult": false,
      "overview": "Wisecracking mercenary Deadpool battles the evil and powerful Cable and other bad guys to save a boy's life.",
      "release_date": "2018-05-15"
    },
    {
      "vote_count": 6657,
      "id": 284053,
      "video": false,
      "vote_average": 7.4,
      "title": "Thor: Ragnarok",
      "popularity": 190.16373,
      "poster_path": "/rzRwTcFvttcN1ZpX2xv4j3tSdJu.jpg",
      "original_language": "en",
      "original_title": "Thor: Ragnarok",
      "genre_ids": [
        28,
        12,
        14,
        878,
        35
      ],
      "backdrop_path": "/kaIfm5ryEOwYg8mLbq8HkPuM1Fo.jpg",
      "adult": false,
      "overview": "Thor is on the other side of the universe and finds himself in a race against time to get back to Asgard to stop Ragnarok, the prophecy of destruction to his homeworld and the end of Asgardian civilization, at the hands of an all-powerful new threat, the ruthless Hela.",
      "release_date": "2017-10-25"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set you state to:

```
this.state = {
    movies : {
        results: []
    }
}
```

So, the `this.state.movie.results[]` now exists. There will be no error.And Instead of

```
<CardArray popularMovies={popularMovies}/>
```

You should do

```
<CardArray popularMovies={this.state.movies.results[0]}/>
```

On the way that you did, you're trying to get the result before the request is done. So, that's why you receive the error, because the request isn't done already.

Delete the line below

```
var popularMovies = this.state.movies.results[0]; //this line has error
```